# how to deal with this prof when he gives you his lowest grade?

Tags: research-process, professorship, grades, coursework

Now our marks came out and the average is 94 and he gave me 2 marks less than the average of the class. (This means that I have got the lowest grade in the class)

I am overthinking these days and getting a headache.
I really want to figure out what is his intention and why is he playing with my future?

I always study hard to get everything done in high quality; I always compare my work with other classmates to correct myself; I do not know why he gave me his lowest grades?

Should Ph.D. students get higher than master students? is there any range?
or 
I am getting this just because I am a girl...

Comment: What country is this? What language is the course offered in?

Comment: Maybe you got the grade you did because your work warranted it? You saw some of the other students' work, but not all of it; you don't know exactly what the grading criteria were or how they were applied to your work or anyone else's; it's hard for you to know whether your complete body of work was really better than anyone else's.

Comment: nikki, maybe your work warranted a lower grade and maybe it was discrimination. How do _you_ know it is the latter case? Please clarify your question by explaining.

Comment: @Thomas, I did my presentations and I did my project, part of my project was dependent on data that was coming from another student. I did all that I could do.

Comment: `the average is 94 and he gave me 2 marks less than the average of the class` It sounds like you still got a pretty good grade. I don't see how you can jump to the conclusion that it was discrimination.

Comment: You should assume the grading is fair unless there is a reason to believe otherwise, which you don't seem to have.

Comment: "I really want to figure out what is his intention and why is he playing with my future?" Sounds to me that you are overthinking this. I also agree with Thomas above, 94 sounds high if out of 100. Also, @ff524 is trying to offer you thoughts but you are criticizing their comments with your response... You sound biased to your own thoughts without trying to look at this as a whole.

Comment: You're mixing together multiple issues here.  TA positions going to PhD students before masters students?  No surprise whatsoever.  Supervisors spending more time with his PhD advisees and hounding them until they learn the material, because they have to use it in their future research?  No surprise there.  Funding going to what the PhD students need first?  No surprise.

Comment: And I'm not sure how getting a laptop would help if your work needs a strong GPU... what would really benefit you is a remote login to a workstation with GPU horsepower levels that could never exist in a laptop (power and cooling requirements)

Comment: I'm a bit confused in how big of a difference 2 marks is, and what grading system you are working under - if you mean you got a 92 when a 94 was the average, I'd consider that a meaningless difference and not even worth thinking about, as in the US that pretty much means you got an A or an A- and is fine either way. But if you mean you got a C when everyone else got an A, that of course suggests the professor really thinks you did not do well at all, and would be worth requesting to meet with them and ask if they can help you understand why your grade was so low. Could you clarify the grade?

Comment: @BrianH: A grading system that makes a 92 a C and a 96 an A is absurd. Besides, wouldn’t most schools have a policy that grades in the 90s should be A’s?

Comment: @aeismail What I'm unsure about is where the "92" comes from - the 94 is from the OP, and then they say "two marks", but they never specify what they mean by that term. Is marks percentage points, or is it "letter grades"? In different countries I've heard points, marks, and grades all used in such an odd variety of ways that I'm never sure how they might map to my US-specific understanding of the terms, and I'm not even sure the where the OP is uses a letter grade scale at all. But I've heard people referring to a C as "two marks below an A", so I want to make sure we aren't misunderstanding

Comment: Did you ask the professor to explain the grade? I'm sure he's better able to than we are.

Answer (score 6):

You should assume the grading is fair, unless there is a reason to believe otherwise. Based on your question and comments, I don't see any reason to believe that discrimination is involved.

You state that you did everything that was required, just like the other students. That doesn't mean you should get exactly the same grade as them. Perhaps your presentation was not as clear as the others or your project had some minor flaws. It is very hard for you to judge that yourself -- you are neither an expert like the professor is nor objective in self-evaluation.

You received a 92, which is below the class average of 94. To me, that still sounds like a good grade and you shouldn't be concerned. Trying to argue for every last point is not productive -- it's called grade grubbing.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel you're being discriminated against, approach the support services of your university. If you don't know what they are, try approaching the head of department, or if you feel the discrimination is coming based on your gender & the HoD is male, approach a female faculty member. Before you do this, make sure the things you're complaining about aren't normal procedure at your institution - for example, most people would not find it surprising that PhD students are offered teaching assistantships preferentially over Masters students.

I should say that in this kind of dispute, evidence will be paramount. It doesn't sound like the evidence you have is strong; certainly what you've written wasn't enough to convince the people who've left a comment. You probably will want something more tangible before escalating the dispute: some kind of paper trail that shows the professor is not being fair.

Comment: More accurately: If you _have evidence_ that you are being discriminated against....